# How to pass shell variable to pig param file

Tags: apache-pig

How we can pass shell variable to pig param file. As an example I have a shell variable defined as DB_NAME. i would like to define my pig parameter file as

p_db_nm=$DB_NAME

I tried like above which does not work and i did try like echo $DB_NAME does not work either.

I'm aware that i can pass this by using -param in command line but i have many variables which i would like to put it in param file but the values will be defined in shell script. I searched many topics in google and didn't have any luck!!!

My question is similar what was posted in http://grokbase.com/t/pig/user/09bdjeeftk/is-it-possible-to-use-an-env-variable-in-parameters-file but i see no workable solution is posted.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

you can pass parameter file using –param_file option.

if Parameter File named "pig.cfg" defined like below,

```
p_db_nm=$DB_NAME
```

in the shell, pig command will be like this,

```
pig -param_file pig.cfg
```

and finally in your pig, you can use does variables named by KEY in the cfg file. (in this case, $p_db_nm)